# Calling function from inside loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

How could I turn `var data{}` into a function and call it within my loop so that new data is sent with each iteration through the array. The array value should be updated with a different record during each call.

I am confused on how I can call a function from the loop and can I just turn data{} into a function or do I need to do something else?

**Script**

```
//Input tenants "ABC, DEF, GHI....."
var tens = "ABC, DEF, GHI"
console.log(tens);

var realten = "ABC, DEF, GHI"
var realten = realten.split(',');
console.log(realten);

var letters = tens.split(',').map(string=>string.trim());
console.log(letters);


//Data Start

//Data function


function tenfunc() {
var data = {};

var caller_id = "caller";
data.caller_id = caller_id;

var description = "description";
data.description = description;

//Convert tens to proper format
var site = {};

switch (realten[0]) {

    case 'ABC':
        site = "A B.C";
        break;

    case 'DEF':
        site = "D E.F";
        break;

    case 'GHI':
        site = "G H.I";
        break;
}

var u_department = site;
data.u_department = u_department;
console.log(data)
}
//End Data
//POST options
  var options = {
    'endpoint': 'test',
    'path':'/api/table/records', 
    'method': 'POST',
    "headers": {
    "Authorization": "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
        } };
        
//I create following function:
function sendData(data) {
    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
            console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
            console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
        });
        req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
}

//end try send for each array item:
for (var i=0; i<letters.length;i++) {
   sendData(data);
}
```

Comment: Well, the whole section of your code from `var data = {};` to `console.log(data)` which is supposed to be run for each letter is outside of your loop. It's only executed exactly once, with `realten[0]`, and the `data` never changes afterwards when you're looping over the letters.

Comment: Hi @Bergi , that's what I see in my logs and I understand that. My problem is I don't know how to also loop through the data with each iteration in the array. It doesn't help my switch is in there too

Comment: You don't want to loop through the data. You want to loop through the `letters`, and create new data on every iteration. Just move the code inside the loop - or even better put it inside a function, and call that function from the loop.

Comment: Could I turn the 'data{}' part into a function and then call that with each iteration?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Make the realten that you are switching on a parameter, so that you can pass the different values from your array to create different data objects.

Comment: I'm still stuck, not sure how I call the function from the loop to pass through each iteration

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question to include the attempt you've made to write the function? The call should basically look like `var data = getTenantData(letters[i]); sendData(data);`

Comment: I added 'function `tenfunc()` for my `data{}` thinking that would be enough